Unable to use the sepolia etherscan api key after correctly putting in the value? Am I missing something?
I keep getting this error constantly even after regenerating new keys and re entering them in my dotenv file. Any reason I get this?
HardhatVerifyError: Invalid API Key (#err2)
    at Etherscan.verify


Have you installed the dotenv package? Please share the content of your hardhat.config.js file.
